# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clientModules')

Tags: next.js

The project's pages work fine with npm run dev and I do not get these errors with the pages with vercel --prod. The problems show up when I generate a production build and run the app with next start.

With next@14.0.4 I got
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ppr') so I downgraded to next@14.0.1.
Now I am getting multiple instances of
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clientModules')

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clientModules') at u (/Users/donovanwhite/art_folio/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:108:22420) at /Users/donovanwhite/art_folio/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:108:23409 at nk (/Users/donovanwhite/art_folio/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:28:38654) at nC (/Users/donovanwhite/art_folio/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:28:54802) at nk (/Users/donovanwhite/art_folio/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:28:51563) at nC (/Users/donovanwhite/art_folio/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:28:54802) at nw (/Users/donovanwhite/art_folio/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:28:38210) at nk (/Users/donovanwhite/art_folio/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:28:38805) at nC (/Users/donovanwhite/art_folio/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:28:54802) at nk (/Users/donovanwhite/art_folio/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:28:51563) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clientModules') at u (/Users/donovanwhite/art_folio/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:108:22420) at /Users/donovanwhite/art_folio/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:108:23409 at nk (/Users/donovanwhite/art_folio/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:28:38654) at nC (/Users/donovanwhite/art_folio/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:28:54802) at nj (/Users/donovanwhite/art_folio/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:28:60948) at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:346:14) at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/donovanwhite/art_folio/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:28:76278) at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17) at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clientModules') at u (/Users/donovanwhite/art_folio/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:108:22420) at /Users/donovanwhite/art_folio/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:108:23409 at nk (/Users/donovanwhite/art_folio/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:28:38654) at nC (/Users/donovanwhite/art_folio/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:28:54802) at nj (/Users/donovanwhite/art_folio/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:28:60948) at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:346:14) at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/donovanwhite/art_folio/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:28:76278) at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17) at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)`

Comment: I also have this error without having touched my code.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem few days ago, for  context i was converting my Vite-React-SPA to NextJS for SSR and SSG, then also host it on Vercel (the Vite version was already hosted).

I found the problem from restructuring the filepaths (I was using App router), then i run debug. It's painful way of doing it yes. but i did found the problem.

on my file arch `app/(group_folder)/@footer/page`, there was a missing import statement here. **AND**  because it was not in the root `app/` where homepage(`/page`) was located, it causes build error for some reason. So the idea was if you're using `@slots` then don't put them inside other folders and keep them in the root folder of your pages along with the `/page.js*jsx`.

like this

```
~app/page.jsx
~app/@footer/page.jsx
~app/@navigation/page.jsx
```

that's how i fixed this error

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clientModules')`

Since Im new to this and don't understand the intricacies of server and client components yet i may be wrong with this approach so if anyone can edit this so its more readable i would be more than glad.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that I had was that my routes were conflicting. I had one folder that was (homepage), meaning that the route was effectively "/". However, I also  left a page.tsx file in the root directory, which had "/" as its route as well. Make sure that you don't have any overlap between folders that aren't included in the route structure and their root folders.